# call to mapStateToProps appears to pass wrong state object

Tags: javascript, error-handling, react-redux

I am working on my first React-Redux app.

This is the code of my reducer (I only have one):

```
const CalculationsReducers = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case CalculationsActions.LOAD_CALCULATIONS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                calculations: [{
                    id: 'abc',
                    name: 'test',
                    date: 'test',
                    status: 'in progress'
                }]
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

This is the code of my 'mapStateToProps' function I use with connect()

```
const mapStateToProps = (s) => {
    return  {
        calculations: s.calculations ||[]
    };
};
```

When I dispatch an action with type LOAD_CALCULATIONS, I can see a log trace (using react-logger), but the state object seems very strange to me. Can someone point me my error?

[log trace using react-logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw5GL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The workflow looks good to me. The state object also looks fine, but you might want to change the alias when importing reducer to configure your store, to make it more intuitive.

In your configure store file:

```
import calculations from 'reducers/CalculationReducer';
```

Note that it requires you to export `CalculationReducer` as default. Then you will see `calculations` instead of `CalculationReducer` in your state object.

And I noticed you have a `payload` along with your action but never got handled in reducer. If you need it in state object then handle it in reducer using `action.payload`.